# Draw9patch not displaying correctly in latest release

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have an issue, where I am setting an EditText background to be a draw9patch, but it doesn't seem to be working. Would appreciate some help with getting this to work.

The problem is-
-9patch file operating like a regular png
-not stretching correctly
-black pixels are visible on screen

The Code I am using to display the editText is:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_confsms_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_sms_conf_toNum"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/speechbubble"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal|center" 
      android:imeOptions="actionNone" 
      android:isScrollContainer="true" 
      android:lines="10"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

and its coming out looking like:

(see left image) 
[image: example output]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this previously, and I suspect it may have been a bug in the Android tools. Try:

1. Upgrading to r19 tools
2. A complete clean rebuild

Can't say it was definitely the older tools version, but I used to see this issue often, and now not at all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating but it didn't seem to fix it.  Then I noticed on some other draw 9 patches that you need to have a large content area and not just mark the outline with single pixels.  Which made the 9 patch valid and working! woot!